# Heroku Node.js App Crashing | module.js:340 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express

My Heroku app is crashing, I believe before it even gets to the Procfile.  I am experiencing the same problem as here:

[Cannot execute Node.js app on Heroku successfully (crashes each time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357523/cannot-execute-node-js-app-on-heroku-successfully-crashes-each-time)

The only difference is that my package.json file has Express included

```
package.json
  {
     "name": "weathersocket",
     "version": "0.0.1",
     "description": "text based weather",
     "main": "weather.js",
     "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "repository": {
         "type": "git",
         "url": "https://github.com/agreen757/weathersocket.github.io"
         },
     "keywords": [
     "demo",
     "heroku",
     "weather"
   ],
   "author": "Adrian Green",
   "license": "MIT",
   "bugs": {
     "url": "https://github.com/agreen757/weathersocket.github.io/issues"
   },
   "homepage": "https://github.com/agreen757/weathersocket.github.io",
   "dependencies": {
     "body-parser": "^1.6.6",
     "consolidate": "^0.10.0",
     "cookie-parser": "^1.3.2",
     "express": "^4.8.6",
     "mongodb": "^1.4.9",
     "socket.io": "^1.0.6",
     "swig": "^1.4.2"
   }
 }
```

I have tried to the foreman utility locally and everything works properly.

My main weather.js file contains:

```
server.listen(4000);
console.log("Express server started on 4000");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:  Heroku logs

```
`2014-08-28T14:29:14.866955+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-08-28T14:29:18.414238+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-28T14:29:18.414259+00:00 app[web.1]: > node weather.js
2014-08-28T14:29:18.414257+00:00 app[web.1]: > weathersocket@10.3.1 start /app
2014-08-28T14:29:18.414260+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-28T14:29:18.755300+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-28T14:29:18.755380+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2014-08-28T14:29:18.755637+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2014-08-28T14:29:18.755646+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2014-08-28T14:29:18.757013+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2014-08-28T14:29:18.757015+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2014-08-28T14:29:18.757011+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io'
2014-08-28T14:29:18.757016+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-08-28T14:29:18.757017+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2014-08-28T14:29:18.757019+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/weather.js:6:10)
2014-08-28T14:29:18.757020+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2014-08-28T14:29:18.757022+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2014-08-28T14:29:18.757023+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2014-08-28T14:29:18.757025+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2014-08-28T14:29:18.757026+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
2014-08-28T14:29:18.765774+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-28T14:29:18.770873+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2014-08-28T14:29:18.770460+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! weathersocket@10.3.1 start: `node weather.js`
2014-08-28T14:29:18.770720+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 8
2014-08-28T14:29:18.770945+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the weathersocket@10.3.1 start script.
2014-08-28T14:29:18.771539+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the weathersocket package,
2014-08-28T14:29:18.771696+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2014-08-28T14:29:18.771844+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2014-08-28T14:29:18.772002+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node weather.js
2014-08-28T14:29:18.772821+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
2014-08-28T14:29:18.773778+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
2014-08-28T14:29:18.772468+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2014-08-28T14:29:18.773030+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command "/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2014-08-28T14:29:18.773608+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
2014-08-28T14:29:18.772297+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls weathersocket
2014-08-28T14:29:18.775689+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
2014-08-28T14:29:18.772151+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2014-08-28T14:29:18.773383+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! cwd /app
2014-08-28T14:29:18.775539+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2014-08-28T14:29:18.773965+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2014-08-28T14:29:18.776097+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not ok code 0
2014-08-28T14:29:18.775840+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2014-08-28T14:29:19.793237+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-08-28T14:29:16.891824+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2014-08-28T14:29:19.781258+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1`
```

Comment: Well, it might be not the answer, but I had a similar problem with my golang app deployed on heroku. The app was crashing because I was setting the port manually, like you do. Try to change `server.listen(4000)` to `server.listen(process.env.PORT)` and let heroku decide which port to use. If it solves the problem, you can set the port using heroku configs: `heroku config:set PORT=4000`.

Comment: I just tried that and no dice, I will keep the port as process.env.PORT to be on the safe side though.  Thanks.

Comment: You could also update your question with some logs. `heroku logs`

Comment: I've just tried to deploy your app. I used sources from your github link, copied `package.json` from your post and created a Procfile `web: node weather.js`. Although I've ran into another problem and solved it using [this solution].(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987571/node-js-app-works-locally-but-heroku-says-missing-module). App is running fine on heroku  now. Are you using the same sources? What's inside your Procfile?

Comment: i think that error at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15) is because is not finding a module, therefore makes me think you are missing some node package in your dependencies, couldnt be that? im seeing the socket.io, but behaves like is not installed

Comment: http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/06/04/deploying-your-first-node-dot-js-and-socket-dot-io-app-to-heroku/

Comment: @SantiagoRebella yes - socket.io is installed locally in the node_modules folder which I have pushed to heroku.

Comment: @fakemeta My Procfile has the same `web: node weather.js`. What is the other problem that you saw?

Comment: @MonsterWimp757 Well, your log says node can't find `socket.io` module.  When I tried to deploy the app `socket.io` was fine, but `indexof` module was missing (this module is used by `socket.io`), so I ran `git add -A --force` before committing and pushing the app to heroku.

Comment: in my opinion is better not to include node_modules, but to be sure package.json has all its dependenices declared

Comment: Okay - I just deleted the Heroku app and recreated it and it gave me no problems and is up and running.  I guess this was needed after implementing all of your changes - I will look into this further to try to isolate one method that was the fix.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few things you could improve, as fakemeta states in his commentary, you should be using the heroku variables to listen port and to have the IP.

You should also include in your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "main": "server.js"
```

So the system know what to do and where is your express server

//-------------EDIT----------------------------//

Cant you try to deploy without node_modules folder?, once you push heroku will install those packages, i mean at least just for debugging purposes

Comment: Are you asking where my express server is?  I added those lines to my package.json file and still have the same error message.  Isnt this scripts area handled by the Procfile?

Comment: no, im telling you that you should tell the system where your server is, as far as i understand is taken from your package.json

Comment: I have updated that section of the package.json and I still have the same issue

Comment: I have removed the node_modules folder and now my error log includes `Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io'`

Comment: that error was already there, look at the 12 line of your question above, that is way i thought maybe doing that would reinstall your modules in heroku side