# Cannot Deploy Node.js app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I know this is the same question that this guy had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357523/cannot-execute-node-js-app-on-heroku-successfully-crashes-each-time/10357591#10357591) but I cannot comment yet as I don't have 50 reputation.

I tried following the answers that question provided but it is still having the same error with Heroku not being able to find 'express'. However, express is showing up in my dependencies in the packages.json and is all running correctly locally. I also "npm install express --save" as well as trying it with a -g flag. What else can I do so that Heroku can find 'express'?

My **package.json** contains:

```
{
  "name": "spark",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "MAXXtreme",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "engines": {
      "node": "6.11.2",
      "npm": "5.5.1"
    },
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-fileupload": "^0.3.0",
    "express-messages": "^1.0.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^4.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.12.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```

My **app.js** contains:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./config/database');

// Connect to db
mongoose.connect(config.database);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
});

// Init app
var app = express();

// View engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Set public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Start the server
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server started on port ' + port);
});
```

Here are the **logs** from Heroku CLI:

```
2017-10-30T13:22:23.512366+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user matt@steeltechmfg.com
2017-10-30T13:22:23.512366+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user matt@steeltechmfg.com
2017-10-30T13:22:23.607220+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user matt@steeltechmfg.com
2017-10-30T13:22:23.607220+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user matt@steeltechmfg.com
2017-10-30T13:28:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user matt@steeltechmfg.com
2017-10-30T13:29:04.387219+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user matt@steeltechmfg.com
2017-10-30T13:28:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-10-30T13:29:04.401658+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user matt@steeltechmfg.com
2017-10-30T13:29:04.387219+00:00 app[api]: Deploy dc2a122a by user matt@steeltechmfg.com
2017-10-30T13:29:06.586186+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node --debug=5858 app.js`
2017-10-30T13:29:08.458266+00:00 app[web.1]: Debugger listening on [::]:5858
2017-10-30T13:29:08.521127+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:471
2017-10-30T13:29:08.521129+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2017-10-30T13:29:08.521130+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2017-10-30T13:29:08.521131+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-10-30T13:29:08.521131+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
2017-10-30T13:29:08.521132+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
2017-10-30T13:29:08.521133+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
2017-10-30T13:29:08.521134+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-10-30T13:29:08.521134+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-10-30T13:29:08.521135+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:1:77)
2017-10-30T13:29:08.521135+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-10-30T13:29:08.521136+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-10-30T13:29:08.521136+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-10-30T13:29:08.521137+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-10-30T13:29:08.521138+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-10-30T13:29:08.617580+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-10-30T13:29:08.620539+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-10-30T13:29:08.598008+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Comment: try placing `"engines": {"node": "6.11.2","npm": "5.5.1"},` outside the dependencies object

Comment: on local / dev machine ....  wipe node-modules dir, then redo 'npm install' thru 'heroku local' there and see what result locally....

Comment: @Syed Awesome! That worked! I have been searching everywhere for a solution to this and that was the problem. Do you want to make that an answer so that I can accept that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Placing engines outside the dependencies in your package.json

```
{
  "name": "spark",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "MAXXtreme",
  "license": "MIT",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.2",
    "npm": "5.5.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-fileupload": "^0.3.0",
    "express-messages": "^1.0.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^4.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.12.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```